# Why does my linux entropy have such a low upper limit?

Tags: linux, performance, unix, encryption, cryptography

I noticed I was getting poor performance when running cryptographic operations.

I ran `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

After some testing using `watch` and my own observations I can see that my entropy levels never surpass 200!

Even when I generate entropy using mouse movements etc. (when my computer is completely idle) it briefly surpasses 200 then suddenly dips back down below it for no reason.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't know why the entropy is low, but maybe you can try rng-tools to increase the entropy.

Comment: use `urandom` instead of `random`; there's no need to use `random` ever.

Comment: I observe the same thing on our RHEL6 VMs, the `entropy_avail` is always below the magic limit of ~200 (observed on about a dozen hosts, over a period of a month) while on our RHEL7 VMs (several dozens) it's usually somewhere around 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the entropy-accumulating system has only about 200 bits of state, and simply cannot get more "unknown" than that.  The people most concerned about having enough entropy tend to be cryptologists, and 200 bits of entropy is plenty for most (maybe all?) cryptographic applications.

Comment: certainly not all ... think of creating OTPs

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 To create an OTP, you would use a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) to generate a stream of data based on the entropy pool. You wouldn't use the entropy pool directly. 200 bits of entropy is perfectly adequate.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage ... sadly that does not hold for an OTP ... csPrng ... the P for "pseudo" is the problem ... the requirement for OTP is pure entropy or you weaken the security to the security of said csprng, which is in every possible case less than the security of OTP ... if the seed fot the csprng is 200 bit, then the complexity to break/guess that is that 200 bit or less ... far away from the security of OTP

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 With 200 bits of entropy, a trillion computers testing a trillion entropy states per second would have a less than one-in-a-trillion chance of breaking the OTP before the sun turns into a red giant and swallows up the earth. I don't see this as a security risk.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage ... good point ... but i did not say that it would be a possible way for an attack at currently available computational ressources ... see it this way: a sufficiently improved computer will possibly one day be able to solve the problem ... if you demand pure entropy as OTP key, it does not matter how much computational power you can get your hands on ... it simply becomes impossible to tell the plaintext apart from every other valid message of same length ... even if you can get a computer that can test all 200000 bit keys in seconds ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 "a sufficiently improved computer will possibly one day be able to solve the problem" — No it won't. Not in this solar system.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Your algorithm wouldn't be an OTP by definition.  A brute force against a 200bit secret is obviously futile, but your stream cipher - the algorithm stretching this 200 bits into the length of your message prior to XOR - could be susceptible to attack perhaps now, perhaps with mathematical or computational advances.  That is not the case with a OTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can substantially improve the available entropy with [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/). It may be already included in your distribution. Centos/Redhat users can install it from the epel repository.

> Haveged was created to remedy low-entropy conditions in the Linux
>   random device that can occur under some workloads, especially on
>   headless servers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. 200 bits of entropy is more than enough.

Here's a quote from [RFC 4086 (Randomness Requirements for Security)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4086#section-3):

> **3.1.  Volume Required**
>
> How much unpredictability is needed?  Is it possible to quantify the
> requirement in terms of, say, number of random bits per second?
>
> The answer is that not very much is needed.  For AES, the key can be
> 128 bits, and, as we show in an example in Section 8, even the
> highest security system is unlikely to require strong keying material
> of much over 200 bits.